# Haxe iteration on Dynamic

Tags: arrays, for-loop, loops, haxe, iterable

I have a variable of type `Dynamic` and I know for sure one of its fields, lets call it `a`, actually is an array. But when I'm writing

```
var d : Dynamic = getDynamic();
for (t in d.a) {
}
```

I get a compilation error on line two:

> You can't iterate on a Dynamic value, please specify Iterator or Iterable

How can I make this compilable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haxe can't iterate over `Dynamic` variables (as the compiler says).

You can make it work in several ways, where this one is probably easiest (depending on your situation):

```
var d : {a:Array<Dynamic>} = getDynamic();
for (t in d.a) { ... }
```

You could also change `Dynamic` to the type of the contents of the array.

Comment: Is it possible to use multiple types an an Array<Dynamic>, such as `[0, "Second element", ["Nested array here!"], "another string"]`?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do the same is to use an extra temp variable and explicit typing:

```
var d = getDynamic();
var a: Array<Dynamic> = d.a;
for (t in a) { ... }
```